# How to add an authorized app to Windows Firewall with both Private and Public profiles checked?

Tags: c#, vb.net, firewall, windows-firewall

I need to add SQL Server to the firewall with both **Private** and **Public** checked. Ive been trying to mess around with the firewall profile but there doesnt seem to be an option to set it to both.

```
Dim ruleSQL As INetFwAuthorizedApplication = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwAuthorizedApplication")
    ruleSQL.Name = "12 SQL Test"
    ruleSQL.IpVersion = NET_FW_IP_VERSION_.NET_FW_IP_VERSION_ANY
    ruleSQL.ProcessImageFileName = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.EDGESQL2019\MSSQL\Binn\sqlservr.exe"
    ruleSQL.Scope = 0
    ruleSQL.Enabled = True




    Dim firewall As INetFwMgr = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwMgr")

    Dim tfwpolicy As INetFwPolicy = firewall.LocalPolicy


    Dim ppolicy As INetFwProfile = tfwpolicy.GetProfileByType(NET_FW_PROFILE_TYPE_.NET_FW_PROFILE_STANDARD)

    ppolicy.AuthorizedApplications.Add(ruleSQL)
```

Comment: Have you checked out INetFwPolicy2? I think it supports selecting profiles using a bitmask. Also check out this example in C# which adds a rule to all profiles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641839/programmatically-add-an-application-to-all-profile-windows-firewall-vista